# SAPui5 table multiLables and multiSorting

Tags: sorting, sapui5, col

I'm developing in SAPui5 one table, and have 1 column with 2 data in one cell (product name & company).
I use the multiLables option for show the title, but I need for each title one sort function.
Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
//Create an instance of the table control
    var oTable2 = new sap.ui.table.Table('table1',{
        visibleRowCount: 12,
        selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
        navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,
        editable: false,
    });

    //Define the columns and the control templates to be used
    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column('colkag', {
        visible: false,
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "kag"}),
        template: "kag",
        sortProperty: "kag",
        filterProperty: "kag",
    }));
    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column('colname', {
        multiLabels: [
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Fondsname"}), 
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Verwaltungsgesellschaft"}) ],
        template: new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({title:"{name}", text:"{kag}"}),
        sortProperty: "name",
        filterProperty: "name",
        width: "400px"
    }));
```

And this is the result:

[image: table with multiLables]

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a way to sort the table through the title? Or the title AND the text?

Comment: I want, wen click on "Fondsname" header order for value {name}, and when click on "Verwaltungsgesellschaft" order for {kag}

Comment: I am still looking, but it seems, that SAPUI5 doesnt offer this option. We will be forced to write an own method I think.

Comment: I think so, but is not normal because allow the multiple headers but no multiple sorting for column when click on differents headers ....

Comment: Exactly my thinking process. One more flaw in SAPUI5 found :)

Comment: This question needs to be generalized & simplified (e.g. show us only the minimum of code necessary to understand the problem) and you need to be more clear about what you want. E.g. show us an example of what's happening that's wrong and of what should be happening instead